# codeigniter moving from localhost to server

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

getting 404 error

> 404 Page Not Found
>
> The page you requested was not found.

config.php

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');



$config['base_url'] = 'http://myhost/sitedir';


$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

default controlerr

```
class MY extends CI_Controller{


    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

         // language
        if($this->input->post("lang")){
            $this->load->model("language");
            $this->language->lang($this->input->post("lang"));
        }

        // !language

        //$this->lang->load("ge");
        if (!$this->session->userdata('lang'))
            $this->lang->load("ge");
        else
        $this->lang->load($this->session->userdata('lang'));
    }

    /**
     * mtavari gverdis controleri
     */
    function index(){
        $this->load->model("dbs");
        $data['products'] = $this->dbs->get_products_by_limit("products",7);
        $this->load->view("header");
        $this->load->view("index_page",$data);
        $this->load->view("footer");
    }

}
```

uploaded default ci package in other directory and it working

i don't have a .htaccess file

sorry for my bad english :(

help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Edit this line as per your server address

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://server_addr/sitedir';-->like this
```

Comment: http://myhost/sitedir'; this is diferrent?

i just inserted sitedir and myhost, i don't wroted my current host and dir

Comment: Yes ofcourse...because you need to run your website on that server only so you need to configured it in your config.php file and also you need to change the database settings as per the server db like root,password,database name in database.php....open your config folder ,edit them then upload it on server

Comment: Look how can you work on turnof db library....put all same as per your localhost..only change db and config of site_url thats it....

Comment: site dir is subfolder like this  http://othersite/mysite

but ai created other simple controller and set as default and it works!

Comment: Then you need to check for db and also you need a .htaccess file.

Comment: i connected to db, i ahve htaccess file

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myshop_demo/
RewriteCond $1 !(index\.php/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: How you are calling it on server...like http://server_adress/yourfolder_name/controller try with index.php as http://server_adress/yourfolder_name/index.php/controller..??

Answer (score 0):

itś Ok. My english i'ts bad too.

If you don't use .httaccess , the  URL for you website must be:

```
'http://website/sitedir/index.php/my'
```

in the defualt package you can use :

; because del defaul, `

> config['index_page'] = '';

, if i don't forget it was set to "welcome".
[My web site](http://maximilianofernandez.net) is in codeignite too, and i had this problems too reference at my incial page.

Your Configuration .php is the same as the my. But i use a . httaccess, to clear the index.php URL.
i hope help a little .

Comment: site dir is subfolder like this  http://othersite/mysite

but ai created other simple controller and set as default and it works!

but this controller don't works :(

Comment: i fixed problem

solution: default cxontroller was name My.php i renamed it to my.php and is worked. thanks all :*

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in routing or HTACCESS Set the variable empty as below.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

try to replace following variable with these parameters ('AUTO', 'PATH_INFO', 'QUERY_STRING', 'REQUEST_URI', and 'ORIG_PATH_INFO') one by one

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for the longest.. In my case, after messsing with the config file, routes, htaccess, etc... In the end the problem was that my CPANEL server was hosted through Linux and linux is case sensitive when it comes to file names. All my controllers had a capital letter for the first letter of the file name. When I changed this to lower case, it worked fine. Maybe this is your issue as well. Good luck to all.